# Confusion related to calculating the probability distribution of a variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this confusion related to calculating the probability distribution of a variable. If I have a variable $x_1$ which has a pdf $p(x_1)$.Lets assume that the distribution is gaussian with mean $X_1$. I sample a point from this distribution lets say $X_1'$.

Now I have another random  variable $x_2$ which has a distribution $p(x_2)$. Its mean is equal to a constant, $X_2$ plus the previous sample $X_1'$. So how can I write the pdf function for this random variable $x_2$. I mean I want its mean to be dependent upon the sample from the distribution of $x_1$.

Comment: Your choice of notation is dreadful. Most people tend to use upper-case (capital) letters for random variables and lower-case letters for the arguments of density functions, real variables, etc.   Also, is p the same function in the two cases?

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $f_X(x)$ with mean $\mu_X$,
and $Y$ is a random variable whose
*conditional* pdf given that $X = a$ is $f_{Y\mid X=a}(y\mid X=a)$
with mean $\mu_1+a$, that is, $E[Y\mid X=a] = \mu_1+a$, then the
*random variable* $E[Y\mid X] = \mu_1 + X$, and 
$$E[Y] = E[E[Y\mid X]] = E[\mu_1+X] = \mu_1+\mu_X.$$
The *unconditional* density of $Y$ is 
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Y\mid X=a}(y\mid X=a)f_X(a)\,\mathrm da.$$
If $X$ is a unit-variance Gaussian random variable, and the conditional
pdf of $Y$ is also a unit-variance Gaussian density, then
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(y-\mu_1-a)^2\right)
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(a-\mu_X)^2\right)\,\mathrm da$$
which, after you combine the exponentials, complete the square, etc.
will work out to be a Gaussian density with mean $\mu_1+\mu_X$.